# MASS equivalent for intel compilers and architectures

Tags: libraries, intel

I was looking for an Intel alternative to MASS IBM libraries (Mathematical Acceleration Subsystem). I know Intel implements MKL libraries, but I d'nt know if there is a specific Math acceleration library in it.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find a function catalog from IBM MASS so I'm not sure if Intel MKL offers all of it. You can take a look [the product brief](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/collateral/XE/mkl_brief.pdf) and see it it's enough for you. Can't you download the trial and take a look at the documentation?

Another numerical library with excellent performance on Intel systems that I really liked is [IMSL from RougueWave](http://www.roguewave.com/DesktopModules/Bring2mind/DMX/Download.aspx?Command=Core_Download&EntryId=487&PortalId=0&TabId=607). The function catalog is [here](http://www.roguewave.com/DesktopModules/Bring2mind/DMX/Download.aspx?Command=Core_Download&EntryId=487&PortalId=0&TabId=607).

Other option is [NAG](http://www.nag.com/numeric/CL/nagdoc_cl09/html/FRONTMATTER/manconts.html). NAG is well known but I don't have first hand experience with it so I won't comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I'll look at them :) I will investigate if mkl has any acceleration package inside :)